# GPS tracking gives me wrong path

Tags: coordinates, gps

I am having trouble collecting GPS coordinates. In my case, I need to walk from point **A to point B** and collect the coordinates avoiding any obstacles. I used an android phone and **mapmyrun** app. When I start from point A, I can see it does not start from where I am standing. It shows I am at the other side of the road. While walking along the footpath sometimes the GPS takes me other side of the road and shows my location in a restaurant or in a building whereas I am walking in the footpath. Now I have the coordinates of these walks. How can I remove these errors from the coordinates?

Note I also used other apps like adidas Runtastic. It gives me same problem. The GPS location changes a lot.

Comment: Don't use your phone, try a GPS handheld unit, they offer better accuracy, or get yourself a better phone.

Comment: I tried with three different phone. tried with iPhone X also. Same problem occurs

Comment: My personal experience from creating bike GPS tracks with mobile phone (thousands of km) is that that's about the accuracy you can get/expect from mobile phone. Sometimes it's right on the track, sometimes it wanders few meters left or right.

Comment: Look for a GPS device with a Broadcom 47755 chipset which has Dual-Band GPS (L1+L5) frequencies https://medium.com/@mikehorton/is-dual-band-a-gps-superpower-f7ad6f047d98 will get sub 30cm accuracy without the cost of GNSS corrections networks like RTK/PPP/SSR.

Comment: @Mapperz can I export gpx file from these device?

Comment: @MushfikunnabiNijhum Yes as it will be in mobile phones (example Xiaomi Mi 8 has it). Then you can use any Android Mapping App and export to gpx).

Comment: @Mapperz Please read the medium.com article you reference again.  Nothing there backs your sub 30cm claim.  Even professional GNSS receivers (Septentrio, Trimble, Topcon, etc) do not claim 30cm without corrections.